# Generation of pie chart using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a CSV file with data like:

```
name,age
raju,23
anju,34
manju,56
sanju,56
```

I'm trying to generate a pie chart using gnuplot.
Here's the command I'm executing:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
reset
set terminal wxt
unset key
set datafile separator ","
set xlabel "USERS"
set ylabel "AGE"

plot 'file.csv' using ($0):2:($0):xticlabels(1) with circles lc variable notitle
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say it's not working, what do you mean? What errors do you get? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i am getting circles like a point on the plot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently, [Gnuplot does not support pie charts yet](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#x1-440004.5); but we can draw it by hand.

First, we need to obtain the angles and percentages related to the second column in your datafile:

```
set datafile separator ','
stats 'file.csv' u 2 noout      # get STATS_sum (sum of column 2)

ang(x)=x*360.0/STATS_sum        # get angle (grades)
perc(x)=x*100.0/STATS_sum       # get percentage
```

Then configure the canvas:

```
set size square                 # square canvas
set xrange [-1:1.5]
set yrange [-1.25:1.25]
set style fill solid 1

unset border
unset tics
unset key
```

and draw the pie chart:

```
Ai = 0.0; Bi = 0.0;             # init angle
mid = 0.0;                      # mid angle
i = 0; j = 0;                   # color
yi  = 0.0; yi2 = 0.0;           # label position

plot 'file.csv' u (0):(0):(1):(Ai):(Ai=Ai+ang($2)):(i=i+1) with circle linecolor var,\
     'file.csv' u (1.5):(yi=yi+0.5/STATS_records):($1) w labels,\
     'file.csv' u (1.3):(yi2=yi2+0.5/STATS_records):(j=j+1) w p pt 5 ps 2 linecolor var,\
     'file.csv' u (mid=Bi+ang($2)*pi/360.0, Bi=2.0*mid-Bi, 0.5*cos(mid)):(0.5*sin(mid)):(sprintf('%.0f (%.1f\%)', $2, perc($2))) w labels
```

The first line in the plot command draws the pie chart, where the columns `(0):(0):(1):(Ai):(Ai=Ai+ang($2)):(i=i+1)` are:

- **columns 1-2:** x and y coordinates of the center of the disk
- **column 3:** radius of the disk
- **column 4-5:** begin and end angles of the region
- **column 6:** color of the region

The second and third lines in the plot command place the labels, and the last line puts the percentages in the middle of each region.

The result:
[image: Pie chart in Gnuplot]

References: (1) [Gnuplot surprising](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.cl/2012/12/pie-charting-with-gnuplot.html)  (2) [Gnuplot tricks](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.cl/2009/08/pie-charts-entirely-in-gnuplot.html)

---

### EDIT:

Based on two related questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40466413/2174266) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36783738/2174266)), a new script is proposed:

```
filename = 'test.csv'

rowi = 1
rowf = 7

# obtain sum(column(2)) from rows `rowi` to `rowf`
set datafile separator ','
stats filename u 2 every ::rowi::rowf noout prefix "A"

# rowf should not be greater than length of file
rowf = (rowf-rowi > A_records - 1 ? A_records + rowi - 1 : rowf)

angle(x)=x*360/A_sum
percentage(x)=x*100/A_sum

# circumference dimensions for pie-chart
centerX=0
centerY=0
radius=1

# label positions
yposmin = 0.0
yposmax = 0.95*radius
xpos = 1.5*radius
ypos(i) = yposmax - i*(yposmax-yposmin)/(1.0*rowf-rowi)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# now we can configure the canvas
set style fill solid 1     # filled pie-chart
unset key                  # no automatic labels
unset tics                 # remove tics
unset border               # remove borders; if some label is missing, comment to see what is happening

set size ratio -1              # equal scale length
set xrange [-radius:2*radius]  # [-1:2] leaves space for labels
set yrange [-radius:radius]    # [-1:1]

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
pos = 0             # init angle
colour = 0          # init colour

# 1st line: plot pie-chart
# 2nd line: draw colored boxes at (xpos):(ypos)
# 3rd line: place labels at (xpos+offset):(ypos)
plot filename u (centerX):(centerY):(radius):(pos):(pos=pos+angle($2)):(colour=colour+1) every ::rowi::rowf w circle lc var,\
     for [i=0:rowf-rowi] '+' u (xpos):(ypos(i)) w p pt 5 ps 4 lc i+1,\
     for [i=0:rowf-rowi] filename u (xpos):(ypos(i)):(sprintf('%05.2f%% %s', percentage($2), stringcolumn(1))) every ::i+rowi::i+rowi w labels left offset 3,0
```

This new code results in:
[image: new plot]

Comment: @vagoberto Could you please help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783738/how-to-modify-a-pie-chart-created-by-gnuplot

Comment: @3kstc done! Let me know if it helped. Sorry for the delay, I've had a busy week :)

Comment: hi vagoberto, i copy/pasted &tested the code.. the chart is not drawn, though i see labels.. possibly, the colors for the slices are not set.. how does column-6, passed as a number get converted into rgb color? thanks for the answer, though..

Comment: If you see only labels in the resulting chart, try removing the first row (with labels) from the input CSV.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar as @fracz said, try removing the first line `name,age` in `file.csv`. See my last comment in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36819285/2174266)

Comment: @vagoberto thanks for this post. unforunately, it's not quite working for me. if you have a moment ..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466413/gnuplot-making-use-of-the-yrange-in-pie-charts

Comment: Hello, how could I set the pie chart circles colors? I have noticed that in this case in variable and it not depend of anything.

Comment: @LuisGonzález The color is taken from the sixth column (the one with `colour=colour+1`) and the flag `lc var` or `linecolor variable`.    For example, if `colour==3` the later is equivalent to `linecolor 3`.  By default, there is up to 8 colors chosen cyclically. You can customize the linecolors with e.g. `set linetype 3 linecolor rgb 'red'`

Comment: Hello, is it possible to use exact `set keys` instead of this workaround?

Comment: @genesi5 Are you thinking in the labels? Since these labels are taken from each row of the datafile, every idea I have until now is another workaround :)

Comment: @vagoberto i mean to draw legends with `set keys`. Since current labels are just a point graph with labels along pie, i'm trying to make output flexible as possible. Because we can't (or hardly can) control the blank spaces, space between labels and pie, space between labels, label length, etc. Then i should use preprocessig with different lagnuage (i use perl), and run gnuplot script as stdin block. That helped me a lot when i tried to set dateformat in xtics with gaps and avoiding overlap.

Comment: I tried copying the gnuplot code from the first three boxes of code you posted but it gives me the warning: Skipping data file with no valid points on the last plot command. I copied the csv file exactly. What's wrong here?

Comment: @Nubcake I reproduce this warning with gnuplot 4.6 (I usually work with 5.0). In the second line of the plot command, replace `($1)` by `1`, so it looks like: `u (1.5):(yi=yi+0.5/STATS_records):1 w labels`. Why this works? I don't know :)

Comment: @vagoberto It was a mistake on my part, I included the `name,age` from the csv file :)

Comment: Please include a MWE.

Comment: @Myridium MWE of what?

Comment: @vagoberto of the script. Isn't it part of the GNU philosophy to make scripts modular? What I see here is a hardcoded filename on the first line, and no description of how that file should be formatted. Also you're missing the shebang. Also what is `rowi` and `rowf`? `rowf` appears to be hardcoded to 7 for some reason. I'd like to use the script but I don't have time to reverse engineer it.

Comment: @vagoberto - maybe stop checking SE notifications obsessively and you'll be happier. There is more to life. I have used this site exactly as it was intended. The comment threads are left open because future readers read the same questions. Your answer could do with improvement, which I have suggested in the comments as per the site's decorum.

Comment: Somehow the colors of the boxes don't match the pie colors for me, using `gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 6`. I was able to make it work somehow with trial and error by changing `lc i+1` to `lc i+colour-rowf+1` - it's probably a superfluous expression but works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get a similar result is to pre-process the data.

e.g., given

```
raju,23
anju,34
manju,56
sanju,56
```

We can then calculate, either by hand, or using a script, or using a spreadsheet, the following

```
23 / ( 23+34+56+56) * 360
=48.9940828402367
34 / ( 23+34+56+56) * 360
=72.4260355029586
56 / ( 23+34+56+56) * 360
=119.289940828402
```

and

```
48.9940828402367 +72.4260355029586
=121.420118343195
121.420118343195+119.289940828402
=240.710059171597
240.710059171597 +119.289940828402
=359.999999999999
```

We now create a data file that looks like

```
raju,0,48.9940828402367,1
anju,48.9940828402367,121.420118343195,2
manju,121.420118343195,240.710059171597,3
sanju,240.710059171597,360,4
```

And we can plot that, for e.g., as follows

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.9 noborder
plot 'test.csv' using (0):(0):(1):2:3:4 with circles lc var notitle
```

[image: a pie chart, just 4 blocks of colour, no lables]

Notes:

1. There's no code for labels here, I assume you already know how to add those.
2. Gnuplot always plots circles as circles, regardless of the ratio between x and y axes.