# How to modify a Pie Chart created by GNUPlot

Tags: gnuplot

**Input:**

I have a `myfile.csv` file that has the following information:

```
Shift,Percentage
Day Shift, 39.94
Night Shift, 60.06
```

**GNUPlot Processing:**

The `myfile.csv` file is fed the `pie_chart_generator.gnuplot` file which is:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
reset
set title "\n"
set label 1 "My Pie Chart\nShift Usage Break Down" at graph 0,1.125 left
set terminal wxt
unset key
set datafile separator ","
set terminal png 
set size square
set output "piechart.png"
stats 'myfile.csv' u 2 noout      # get STATS_sum (sum of column 2)

ang(x)=x*360.0/STATS_sum        # get angle (grades)
perc(x)=x*100.0/STATS_sum       # get percentage

#set size square                 # square canvas
set xrange [-1:1.5]
set yrange [-1.25:1.25]
set style fill solid 1

unset border
unset tics
unset key

Ai = 0.0; Bi = 0.0;             # init angle
mid = 0.0;                      # mid angle
i = 0; j = 0;                   # color
yi  = 0.0; yi2 = 0.0;           # label position


plot 'myfile.csv' u (0):(0):(1):(Ai):(Ai=Ai+ang($2)):(i=i+6) with circle linecolor var
```

and was created with this as a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896718/generation-of-pie-chart-using-gnuplot).

**Current Output of Chart:**

This code generates this pie chart:
[image: Output .png pie chart]

**Questions:**

**Q1:** How can I assign colours to each of the sectors of the graph in RGB format?
**Q2:** Is there a way I can place the the labels on the right hand corner?
**Q3:** How can I place the value on the chart?

**Ideal Output of Chart:**
[image]

**Addendum:**

I have further improved my code with the aid of the answer. The code in the answer didn't quiet work for me so I had to tweak it to:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
reset

dataname = 'myfile.csv'
set datafile separator ','

# Get STATS_sum (sum of column 2) and STATS_records 
stats dataname u 2 noout

# Define angles and percentages
ang(x)=x*360.0/STATS_sum        # get angle (grades)
perc(x)=x*100.0/STATS_sum       # get percentage

# Set Output 
set terminal png
set output "piechart.png"
set size square

# Print the Title of the Chart
set title "\n"
set label 1 "My Pie Chart\nShift Usage Break Down" at graph 0,1.125 left

#set terminal wxt
unset key
set key off

set xrange [-1.5:1.5]
set yrange [-1.5:1.5]
set style fill solid 1

unset border
unset tics
unset colorbox

# some parameters 
Ai = 5.0;                     # Initial angle
mid = 0.0;                    # Mid angle

# This defines the colors yellow~FFC90E, and blue~1729A8
# Set palette defined (1 '#FFC90E', 2 '#1729A8')             # format '#RRGGBB'
set palette defined (1 1 0.788 0.055, 2 0.090 0.161 0.659)   # format R G B (scaled to [0,1])


plot for [i=1:STATS_records] dataname u (0):(0):(1):(Ai):(Ai=Ai+ang($2)):(i) every ::2 with circle linecolor palette,\
      dataname u (mid=(Ai+ang($2)), Ai=2*mid-Ai, mid=mid*pi/360.0, -0.5*cos(mid)):(-0.5*sin(mid)):(sprintf('%.2f\%', $2, perc($2))) w labels center font ',10',\
      for [i=1:STATS_records]dataname u (1.45):(i*0.25):1 every ::1 with labels left,\
      for [i=1:STATS_records] '+' u (1.3):(i*0.25):(i) pt 5 ps 4 lc palette 

# first line plot semicircles: (x):(y):(radius):(init angle):(final angle):(color)
# second line places percentages: (x):(y):(percentage)
# third line places the color labels
# fourth line places the color symbols
unset output
```

**Current Output of Chart** *from the code above* **:**

[image]

**Addendum Questions:**

**Q4:** I am having massive difficulty with the labels/titles. I have tried the code in the answer I got the same result. How can I print the titles without printing over each other?

Comment: Just a comment: you changed the first `plot for [i]... every ::i-1::i-1` line to `every ::2`. This way you are drawing the pie-chart **twice** because you read the entire data (`every ::2` reads from line 2 to the end) for each value of `i` (`for [i=1:records]`).  This is why you see overlapped titles.    I would write something like `plot for [i=1:STATS_records] ... every ::i::i`.  Please see my edit at the end of my answer.

Comment: @vagoberto yes! that did the trick! because for other values other then the sample one - it wasn't drawing the pie as a full circle but rather like pacman with its mouth open ( <  but `every ::i::i` did the trick - I too have updated my answer! Thank you....

Comment: I would again politely ask the community to up-vote the question as I have shared a bounty of my own to benefit not only myself but the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [post you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896718/generation-of-pie-chart-using-gnuplot) already suggested a way to place the labels and percentage values. Let me explain the steps, point by point, to achieve this goal. At the end I write the full script.

> **Q3:** How can I place the value on the chart?

Each slice is defined within two angles `(Ai,Af)`. The percentage values should be placed in the middle of each one, at `(x,y)=(0.5*cos(mid), 0.5*sin(mid))`, where `mid=0.5*(Ai+Af)` is the mid-point angle, and `0.5` represents half the radius of the pie-chart.

For the first entry we can set `Ai=0`, and the angle `Af` is calculated from your data as `Af=ang($2)`, where `ang(x)` is defined in your script. 
For the second entry, we update `Ai=Af` and calculate again `Af=ang($2)`, and so on.

Finally, the following line should place the percentages:

```
plot 'myfile.csv' u (mid=Ai+ang($2), Ai=2*mid-Ai, mid=mid*pi/360.0, -0.5*cos(mid)):(-0.5*sin(mid)):(sprintf('%.2f\%', $2, perc($2))) every ::1 w labels center font ',10'
```

**Note:** that the first parenthesis `(mid=Ai+ang($2), Ai=2*mid-Ai, mid=mid*pi/360.0, -0.5*cos(mid))` calculates the angles `Ai` and `mid` (`Af` is actually not needed), and then returns the coordinate `x=-0.5*cos(mid)`.

**Caveat:** both x and y axes **must** have the same ranges:

```
set xrange [-1.5:1.5]
set yrange [-1.5:1.5]
```

> **Q2:** Is there a way I can place the the labels on the right hand corner?

For the colored squares, you can plot points at fixed x, and equally spaced y values with:

```
for [i=1:STATS_records] '+' using (1.3):(i*0.25):(i) pt 5 ps 4 linecolor palette
```

where `STATS_records` is the number of rows of your file (which you already calculated with `stats 'myfile.csv'`). This line uses a pseudo file '+', and the using spec has three columns `(x):(y):(color)`, where `x=1.3` fixed, `y=i*0.25` for `i=1,2,3,...,STATS_records`, and `color=i` is used by `linecolor palette`. The points are filled squares (`pt 5`) with 4 pixels length (`ps 4`).  The colors are drawn in the same order as the respective pie slices.

The labels of each color can be drawn with:

```
plot for [i=1:STATS_records] 'myfile.csv' u (1.45):(i*0.25):1 every ::i::i with labels center font ',10'
```

where the using spec has columns `(x):(y):(name)`. The `x=1.45` value is slightly greater than that used before, and `y=i*0.25` must be the same as those of the colored squares. `name=$1` extract the string from column 1, which is used by `with labels`.

**Note:** You can control the font and size of the labels with `with labels font 'Arial,10'`. You can omit the font name as `font ',10'`.

> **Q1:** How can I assign colours to each of the sectors of the graph in RGB format?

In the last command, I use `linecolor palette`, allowing us to define the colors with

```
set palette defined (1 1 0.788 0.055, 2 0.090 0.161 0.659)
```

where I use the colors in RGB, scaled to [0,1] (yellow-like is 1 0.788 0.055; blue-like is 0.090 0.161 0.659).

**Note:** The pie-chart should be drawn now with:

```
plot for [i=1:STATS_records] dataname u (0):(0):(1):(Ai):(Ai=Ai+ang($2)):(i) every ::i-1::i-1 with circle linecolor palette
```

This is what I obtain with your data

[image: pie-chart]

This is the full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
reset

dataname = 'myfile.csv'
set datafile separator ','

# get STATS_sum (sum of column 2) and STATS_records 
stats dataname u 2 noout    

#define angles and percentages
ang(x)=x*360.0/STATS_sum        # get angle (grades)
perc(x)=x*100.0/STATS_sum       # get percentage

# output 
set terminal png
set output 'piechart.png'
set size square

set title "\n"
set label 1 "My Pie Chart\nShift Usage Break Down" at graph 00.5,0.95 left

set xrange [-1.5:2.5]     # length (2.5+1.5) = 4
set yrange [-2:2]         # length (2+2) = 4
set style fill solid 1

# unset border            # remove axis
unset tics                # remove tics on axis
unset colorbox            # remove palette colorbox 
unset key                 # remove titles

# some parameters 
Ai = 15.0;                # init angle
mid = 0.0;                # mid angle

# this defines the colors yellow~FFC90E, and blue~1729A8
# set palette defined (1 '#FFC90E', 2 '#1729A8')      # format '#RRGGBB'
set palette defined (1 1 0.788 0.055, 2 0.090 0.161 0.659) # format R G B (scaled to [0,1])


plot for [i=1:STATS_records] dataname u (0):(0):(1):(Ai):(Ai=Ai+ang($2)):(i) every ::i::i with circle linecolor palette,\
     dataname u (mid=(Ai+ang($2)), Ai=2*mid-Ai, mid=mid*pi/360.0, -0.5*cos(mid)):(-0.5*sin(mid)):(sprintf('%.2f\%', $2, perc($2))) ever\
y ::1 w labels center font ',10',\
     for [i=1:STATS_records] dataname u (1.45):(i*0.25):1 every ::i::i with labels left,\
     for [i=1:STATS_records] '+' u (1.3):(i*0.25):(i) pt 5 ps 4 lc palette    

# first line plot semicircles: (x):(y):(radius):(init angle):(final angle):(color)
# second line places percentages: (x):(y):(percentage)
# third line places the color labels
# fourth line places the color symbols
unset output
```

**Update:** The original `myfile.csv` has a header (the first line `Shift,Percentage`) that gnuplot don't read correctly. We can ignore this line by commenting it (add a `#` character, e.g. `# Shift,Percentage`), or to place an `every` command starting at 1 in the plot lines:

```
plot for [i=1:STATS_records] dataname u (0):(0):(1):(Ai):(Ai=Ai+ang($2)):(i) every ::i::i with circle linecolor palette,\
     dataname u (mid=(Ai+ang($2)), Ai=2*mid-Ai, mid=mid*pi/360.0, -0.5*cos(mid)):(-0.5*sin(mid)):(sprintf('%.2f\%', $2, perc($2))) ever\
y ::1 w labels center font ',10',\
     for [i=1:STATS_records] dataname u (1.45):(i*0.25):1 every ::i::i with labels left,\
     for [i=1:STATS_records] '+' u (1.3):(i*0.25):(i) pt 5 ps 4 lc palette
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation - the code didn't work first go, so I tweaked it a bit. I currently have the problem with the titles - I have added a detailed description to question - could you please help me?

Comment: I changed the second last `for` to `for [i=1:STATS_records] dataname u (1.45):(i*0.25):1 every ::i::i with labels left,\ `

Comment: I am still a bit uneasy with GNUPlot.  I have `set border` and tried some things from [GuidoLabs](http://labs.guidolin.net/2010/03/how-to-create-beautiful-gnuplot-graphs.html) but I want to create a border around the whole image, So that the title, and the legend sit inside the border - How could I do this?

Comment: See my edit. I changed these lines: `set xrange [-1.5:2.5]`, `set yrange [-2:2]`, `set label 1 "My pie..." at graph 0.05,0.95`, and commented `# unset border`.   Just be sure that `xrange` and `yrange` have the same lengths to have a squared plot.

Answer (score 2):

By tweaking and using Vagobertos well-explained code (because the code didn't work for me) and doing further readings, my code is as follows:

**GNUPlot Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
reset

dataname = 'myfile.csv'
set datafile separator ','

# Get STATS_sum (sum of column 2) and STATS_records 
stats dataname u 2 noout

# Define angles and percentages
ang(x)=x*360.0/STATS_sum        # get angle (grades)
perc(x)=x*100.0/STATS_sum       # get percentage

# Set Output 
set terminal png
set output "piechart.png"
set size square

# Print the Title of the Chart
set title "\n"
set label 1 "My Pie Chart\nShift Usage Break Down" at graph 0,1.125 left

#set terminal wxt
unset key
set key off

set xrange [-1.5:1.5]
set yrange [-1.5:1.5]
set style fill solid 1

unset border
unset tics
unset colorbox

# some parameters 
Ai = 5.0;                     # Initial angle
mid = 0.0;                    # Mid angle

# This defines the colors yellow~FFC90E, and blue~1729A8
# Set palette defined (1 '#FFC90E', 2 '#1729A8')             # format '#RRGGBB'
#set palette defined (1 1 0.888 0.055, 2 0.156 0.455 0.651)   # format R G B (scaled to [0,1])


set palette defined (1 0.961 0.690 0.255, 2 0.180 0.525 0.757)   # format R G B (scaled to [0,1])

plot for [i=1:STATS_records] dataname u (0):(0):(1):(Ai):(Ai=Ai+ang($2)):(i) every ::i::i with circle linecolor palette,\
      dataname u (mid=(Ai+ang($2)), Ai=2*mid-Ai, mid=mid*pi/360.0, -0.5*cos(mid)):(-0.5*sin(mid)):(sprintf('%.2f\%', $2, perc($2))) w labels center font ',16',\
      for [i=1:STATS_records]dataname u (1.45):(i*0.25):1 every ::i::i with labels left font 'Arial-Bold,10',\
      for [i=1:STATS_records] '+' u (1.3):(i*0.25):(i) pt 5 ps 4 linecolor palette 


# ***************************************************   +--------------------         shape code=
#     for [i=1:STATS_records] '+' u (1.3):(i*0.25):(i) pt 8 ps 4 linecolor palette          # empty triangle
#     for [i=1:STATS_records] '+' u (1.3):(i*0.25):(i) pt 9 ps 4 linecolor palette          # solid triangle
#     for [i=1:STATS_records] '+' u (1.3):(i*0.25):(i) pt 7 ps 4 linecolor palette          # solid circle
#     for [i=1:STATS_records] '+' u (1.3):(i*0.25):(i) pt 6 ps 4 linecolor palette          # empty circle


# first line plot semicircles: (x):(y):(radius):(init angle):(final angle):(color)
# second line places percentages: (x):(y):(percentage)
# third line places the color labels
# fourth line places the color symbols



unset output
```

**The Output Piechart:**
[image]