# Jenkins tool to create pie chart

Tags: bash, jenkins, charts, jenkins-plugins, hudson

I have a jenkins job that is running some bash disk usage commands and storing them in a text file.  For example:

```
du -sk /home/user/* > results.txt
```

will output the size in kilobytes of everything in `/home/user/` into `results.txt`

I then want to somehow create a pie chart for `/home/user/` with each line in results.txt being represented as a percentage.  For example if one of the lines in `results.txt` is:

```
100 /home/user/somedir
```

And the total # of kilobytes is `1000` then `/home/user/somedir` should be represented as `10%` on the pie chart.
I want this to be displayed in jenkins.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think `gnuplot` when I read it's about batch graph creating. Unfortunately it doesn't support pie chart yet, more precisely not directly yet. But they're some workaround (dirty tricks with polar coordinates and stuff) that have been shared on SO and SU

- Aug 2015: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31901113/1699311
- May 2019: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55943348/1699311

My second thought was `ggplot2` but you'll need to [learn R](https://www.ossblog.org/grasp-r-programming-open-source-books/) as it's made with that language and as extension for that application. Otherwise, [`plplot` has binding to many programming languages](https://plplot.sourceforge.net/) ; but I'm not sure pie chart are that easy too.

My last thoughts was [mermaidjs](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/pie.html) if you can rearrange your file (a little `awk` should suffice.) The same, you can consider [vega-lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/layer_arc_label.html) which require a little more complex JSON for more features. Same goes for [ervy](https://www.chunqiuyiyu.com/ervy/#started) if you are nodejs guy (I never tried and it has been suggested by a colleague)