Gnuplot - add labels to a pie-chart
I'm drawing a pie chart with the following code:
set xrange [-9:9]
set style fill transparent solid 0.3
plot '-' using 1:2:3:4:5:6 with circles lc var notitle
0    0    5    0    90    7
0    0    5   90   180    7
0    0    5  180   270    7
0    0    5  270   315    9
0    0    5  315   360    9
e


How can I add labels to the columns?
So I would get something similar to:


How do you want to provide the labels? As a 7th column in your data? Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55726163/7295599

Check the following small example.
In order to add labels, simply use the plotting style with labels (check help labels). You better use the same x- and y-range and set the aspect ratio to -1 (check help size).
Script:
### pie chart with labels
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0    0    5    0   120    0xff0000   "a third"
0    0    5  120   210    0x00ff00   "a quarter"
0    0    5  210   270    0x0000ff   "a sixth"
0    0    5  270   315    0xff00ff   "an eighth"
0    0    5  315   351    0xffff00   "a tenth"
0    0    5  351   360    0x00ffff   "the rest"
EOD

set xrange [-6:6]
set yrange [-6:6]
set size ratio -1
set style fill transparent solid 0.3
set key noautotitle
set angle degrees

plot $Data u 1:2:3:4:5:6 w circles lc rgb var, \
        '' u (a=($4+$5)/2, $3*0.7*cos(a)):($3*0.7*sin(a)):7 w labels
### end of script

Result:

